# I am losing a variable... where?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
$id_sent = $_POST['id'];
echo  $id_sent;
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/upload_class.php");

$max_size                      = 1024*250*500;
$my_upload                     = new file_upload;
$my_upload->upload_dir         = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/";
$my_upload->extensions         = array(".pdf");
$my_upload->max_length_filename= 50;
$my_upload->rename_file        = true;
$my_upload->id_search          = $id_sent;

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $my_upload->the_temp_file  = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $my_upload->the_file       = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $my_upload->http_error     = $_FILES['upload']['error'];

    if ($my_upload->upload()) {
        mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE psi_avize SET pdf = 'T' WHERE id = '%s'", $my_upload->id_search));?>
        <table width="800" border="0">
            <tr>
              <th width="167" rowspan="2" scope="col"><img src="images/figure_check_mark_celebrate_anim_md_wm.png" width="129" height="142"></th>
              <th width="471" height="29" scope="col"><div align="left">Succes!</div></th>
              <th width="148" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="104">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table><?php
        echo $my_upload->show_error_string();
    }
}
else {?> <strong>Insert file!</span></p>
  </strong>
  <table width="800" border="0">
    <tr>
      <th width="167" rowspan="2" scope="col"><img src="images/document.png" width="150" height="152"></th>
      <th width="471" height="29" scope="col"><div align="left"></div></th>
      <th width="148" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="104">Max =  5 MB.</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  Load file <form name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <div align="center">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="11%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                <th width="26%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                <th width="51%" scope="col"><div align="left">
                  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_size; ?>" />
                  <?php
                    echo $my_upload->create_file_field("upload", "Select file...", 25, false); ?></div></th>
                <th width="12%" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
                </div></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  </form>   <?php  }
  ?>
```

My problem is that somehow I loose the variable $id_sent (it is sent using POST from other page) and I am not able to query  correctly using id.
When I echo the variable in line 3 is working but after that somehow I am losing that variable and I am not able to use it.
Thank you!

Comment: You don't have an element named `upload` yet alone an input type `file`

Comment: @Fred-ii- u wrong `$my_upload->create_file_field(...`, instead he's missing `id_sent` in the form of file insert

Comment: You should start with a condition to check if the for was submitted. Like.. if (isset($_REQUEST['id']))

Comment: It was sumited. when I echo (line 3) it is right

Comment: Please show the contents of `file_upload` class. Also, please explain what you mean by 'loose the variable'? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili I'm wrong about that, but OP doesn't have an named element called `id`. PHP is looking for `name="id"` as per `$_POST['id']` which will explain the warning.

Comment: No. The file is uploaded but I am not able to correctly identify id in query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ya I meant that ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem you are having is that the `$id_sent` is coming from another page's post. This is the reason you are able to echo it correctly in the first place.

After the current page is loaded, and you click on submit button of the current page's form, the `POST` values from the previous page is overwritten by the `POST` values from this page.

In order to retain the value across this page's post as well, store it in a hidden field like so

```
<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='<? php echo $id_sent; ?>'>
```

So here, the first time around the `$id_sent` is set as the value of `id` from previous page post. It is also set into a hidden field named `id` in this page's form, which will then be considered for subsequent form submissions

Comment: Nice catch, i presumed this was handled by the file_upload class (that the op hasnt shown us) but i expect this is correct

Comment: @Steve: thanks - yeah, even though the question does not seem to make it clear, I think this might be the problem the OP is facing.